# How to get the Status Bar background color to show colorPrimaryDark

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-notification-bar

I have a layout that used to update the background color of the status bar based on `colorPrimaryDark`.

This worked great when the layout's root layout was a `CoordinatorLayout`, but when I switched it to a `LinearLayout` the status bar background is no longer updated.

The source for the layout and a screenshot are pasted below. An example of a layout that works properly is also listed.

Thank you!

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".churches.ChurchesActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

styles-v21.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Status Bar is not colorPrimaryDark

[image: Status Bar is not colorPrimaryDark]

Status Bar is colorPrimaryDark

[image: Status Bar is colorPrimaryDark]

Comment: show us your style.xml

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When posting styles-v21.xml I found that android:statusBarColor was set to transparent:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Changing android:statusBarColor to colorPrimaryDark fixed it. Thank you!

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

Not sure why statusBarColor came into play after switching to a LinearLayout from a CoordinatorLayout. Thank you!

Comment: CoordinatorLayout draws a status bar background when it has a top inset from system windows. By default it uses `colorPrimaryDark` as the drawable to draw.

Comment: Don't know how I would have figured that out! Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

Try this in Activity before set content view

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getFactorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar_color), 0.4f));
}
```

where getFactorColor method is

```
public static int getFactorColor(int color, float factor) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
    hsv[2] *= factor;
    color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this **android:fitsSystemWindows="true"** property for your Linear layout and see.

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason android:fitsSystemWindows="true" did not have the same effect when applied to a LinearLayout as it had when it was applied to CoordinateLayout. Good suggestion! Thank you!

Comment: @Shiva, this is not the correct answer, setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` will only make `LinearLayout` add some paddingTop, it won't make `LinearLayout` draw color on the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>` in your theme or call `window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)` programmatically. But, take note that `navigationBarColor` is introduced since Android Lollipop(API 21), which means `navigationBarColor` is not supported when API < 21.

Answer (score -1):

If you won't get by after trying all these. Just invalidate the cache and restart the projects. definitely this will work.